# Which branches contain this change?

Tags: mercurial

Apologies for asking a dumb question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere...

I have a huge, complex Mercurial repo with a dozen branches on it. About 6 months ago I fixed a bug on branch A. How do I discover which other branches (if any) also contain this change?

One obvious non-answer is to find the change-set in Tortoise Hg and manually follow the tangled revision graph through 6 months of changes until I find the information I'm after. Theoretically that works, but it's far too time-consuming and error-prone for a human to do that by hand.

Surely there's some way to automate this...

P.S. Trying to find Google search terms for this is an exercise in frustration.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the command you want:

```
hg log -r "heads(descendants(XXX) or descendants(destination(XXX)) or destination(XXX) or XXX)" -T "{branch}\n"
```

`XXX` must be replaced with either the hash or the changeset number of the bugfix changeset.

Here's an explanation of the above expression:

```
heads(set)       - only considers the heads of the changeset set
descendants(rev) - only considers all direct descendants of the changeset
destination(rev) - only considers grafts, transplants or rebases of the changeset
rev              - that changeset
```

So the expression means this: All heads that are either:

- descendants of the bugfix changeset
- descendants of grafts, transplants, or rebases, of the bugfix changeset
- grafts, transplants, or rebases, of the bugfix changeset (in case where these have no descendants)
- the bugfix changeset itself (in case this is a head of a branch)

More information about revsets can be found here: [Mercurial Help: revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets).